# If $x^5 ≡ 2 $(mod $17$) then $x ≡ 15 $(mod $17$)

Tags: congruences

How am I suppose to reduce the $x^5$ Should I write the entire table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLT $x^{16}\equiv 1 \mod 17$

So $(x^5)^3x \equiv 8x \equiv 1 \mod 17$

So $16x \equiv -x \equiv 2 \mod 17$

So $x \equiv -2 \equiv 15 \mod 17$

Answer (score 3):

You probably know that $x^{p-1}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ for non-zero $x$. So in our case the exponent we have, $5$, is relatively prime to $p-1=17-1=16$.
So there exist integers $a,b$ such that $5a+16b=1$. (E.g. $a=-3,b=1$) does So $x\equiv x^{5a+16b}\equiv x^{5a}(x^{16})^b\equiv x^{5a}\equiv (x^5)^a\equiv 2^{-3}\equiv 2^{16-3}\equiv 2^{13} \pmod {17}$.

Now $2^{13}$ reduces to $15$ modulo 17.

Comment: So we know 5 and 16 are coprime. How do you get 5a  + 16b = 1 ?

Comment: In general if $\gcd(x,y)=k$, you can always find integers $a,b$ such that $ax+by=k$.

Comment: omg ur absolutely right? I forgot about that theorem. Thanks

Comment: How is $2^{-3}$ = $2^{16-3}$

Comment: Because $2^{16}\equiv 1 \pmod 17$ You can multiply by $(2^{16})^k$ for free anywhere in your calculations.